# Is there a way to update a binding variable attached to an Input text Item in Blazor when using Ctrl +V combination keys?

Tags: asp.net-core, keypress, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this input which is to capture a phone number.
When the user enters a number and press the *"Enter"* Key the Method "KeyWasPressed" is triggered and some validation happens. this works as expected BUT...

When the user copies and pastes the number from excel, for example, the variable `@Phone` doesn't updates its value so when the user presses the *"Enter"* key the validation sends and empty value.

Is there a way to refresh/update `@Phone` variable when some text is pasted to the input control?

Here is a snipped of my code:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" @bind="@Phone" @onkeypress="@(async e => await KeyWasPressed(e))" placeholder="Client Phone Number" />

@code {

    string Phone { get; set; }

    private async Task GetClientInfo()
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Phone))
        {
            notificationMessages = $"Add a phone number";
        }
        else
        {
            showSpinner = true;

            clientInfo = await ApiHelper.GetClientInfoByPhone(Phone);           

            if(clientInfo != null)
            {
                var singleViewId = clientInfo?.SingleViewId;
                var customerNumber = clientInfo?.Accounts?.FirstOrDefault().CustomerNumber;
                var status = clientInfo?.Accounts?.FirstOrDefault().Status;
                showClientInformation = true;

                var CrossSell = clientInfo?.Accounts[0]?.CrossSell;


            }
            else
            {
                showClientInformation = false;
                notificationMessages = $"No client data for this phone ({Phone})";
            }

            showSpinner = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task KeyWasPressed(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            //await GetClientInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Direct solution:

Just use `@bind-value="@Phone" @bind-value:event="oninput"`:

```
<input type="number" @bind-value="@Phone" @bind-value:event="oninput" 
       @onkeyup="@OnUserFinish"/>
<p>@clientInfo</p>

@code {
    protected string Phone { get; set; } 
    protected string clientInfo {get; set;}

    private async Task OnUserFinish(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Enter")
          clientInfo = await Fake_ApiHelper_GetClientInfoByPhone(Phone);      
    }

    private async Task<string> Fake_ApiHelper_GetClientInfoByPhone(string phone)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return $"Client phone: {phone}";
    }
}
```

## Bonus track:

Move to a user friendly debounce version:

```
@using System.Timers;

<input type="number" @bind-value="@Phone" @bind-value:event="oninput" 
       @onkeyup="@HandleKeyUp"/>
<p>@clientInfo</p>

@code {
    protected string Phone { get; set; } 
    protected string clientInfo {get; set;}
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(250);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnUserFinish;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
    }

    void HandleKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        // remove previous one
        aTimer.Stop();

        // new timer
        aTimer.Start();        
    }    

    private void OnUserFinish(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeAsync( async () =>
          {
            clientInfo = await Fake_ApiHelper_GetClientInfoByPhone(Phone);      
            StateHasChanged();
          });
    }

    private async Task<string> Fake_ApiHelper_GetClientInfoByPhone(string phone)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return $"Client phone: {phone}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### The Reason

I could reproduce the same issue. Turns out the reason is when we copy sth & paste into the input, and then press the `Enter` key, the `enter` key event is triggered **before** the `change` event.

See the event sequence:

[image]

Because the Enter KeyPress event is triggered before the change event, the `Phone` property has not been updated yet.

### How to fix

One possible walkaround is to listen the paste event. But unfortunately, there's currently a limitation when using Blaozr's native onpaste (See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14133#issuecomment-533198522).

Since the Team member suggests that we should use `jsinterop`, we can add a `interHelper.handlePaste` function:

```
<script>
    var interHelper={
        handlePaste: function (){
            var node = document.getElementById('phoneInput');
            return node.value;
        },
    }
</script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

And then refresh the latest value manually when pasting:

```
<input id='phoneInput' type="number" class="form-control" @bind="@Phone" 
    @onpaste="HandlePaste"
    @onkeypress="@(async e => await KeyWasPressed(e))" 
    placeholder="Client Phone Number" />

@code {
    ...

    private async Task HandlePaste(ClipboardEventArgs e){
        var str = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("interHelper.handlePaste");
        this.Phone= str;
    }
}
```

#### Demo

Copy "107783" & Paste into the input & Press the `Enter` Key:

[image]